# How to release JDBC connection after accessing entities outside the transaction?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions, lazy-loading

My application uses JPA with Hibernate as the provider, and spring-managed local transactions.

In order to maintain a "long-running persistence context" or conversation, the EntityManager is created once (at the beginning of a use case) on the web-tier (with a call to `EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()`), and is stored in the HttpSession. The EntityManagerFactory is a proxy that will return that same EntityManager when invoked from within a transaction. The same EntityManager is thus accessed by the DAOs to perform CRUD operations with JpaTemplate. All this works fine.

However, I noticed errors about the connection pool being exhausted, and found out the reason : some entities have lazy-loading relationships that are eventually loaded during web page rendering (fields like `#{person.address.street}`).

When a few HttpSession are active, all this works fine because the EntityManager remains open after the transaction ends. As more users connect to the application, the pool gets exhausted because Hibernate does not actually release connections to the pool once it has executed the queries triggered from the web.

The Hibernate connection release mode is set to `auto`, which means (in the case of tomcat with local transaction) `after_transaction`. However, since there's no transaction when a query is executed in the web tier, Hibernate does not release the connection to the pool after it's done the job. It actually releases it on EntityManager close.

Hibernate connection release modes are either `after_statement` or `after_transaction` or `on_close`, but none of them are appropriate for making queries both inside and outside the transaction (`after_statement` should only be used for JTA).

So, the question is "What should I change in order to be able to use lazy-loading relationships in the web-tier and a long-running persistence context ?"

Comment: Looks like you have defined an anti pattern, you may have to implement Session-per-request-with-detached-objects pattern as mentioned here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch02.html

Comment: Looking in your doc, I'd rather say I implemented 2.4.3. Conversations with Extended (or long) session (entities are not detached). Does not look like an anti-pattern.

Comment: Just for clarification, 2.4.3 mentions that session disconnects from the jdbc connection but the transaction is committed on every request. Later we can re-connect the session to the connection. Meaning, hibernate session stays alive for a lengthy period of time but jdbc connections close at the end of request and transactions also commit at the end of the request. Correct?

Comment: That's correct. However there's no JPA api to disconnect the entity manager from its underlying JDBC connection. Hibernate Session provides a disconnect() method for this purpose, and I would expect this method to be invoked by Hibernate's EntityManagerImpl. The only invokers of this method are 2 Spring classes : HibernateTransactionManager (for local pure Hibernate tx) and a synchronization callback (for JTA pure Hibernate tx). But there's no such invocation for JPA, neither from Hibernate, nor from Spring.